# Different styles of walkings or running

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

Could anyone please let me know possible styles of walkings related words in English?
For example: *walking*, *running*, *staggering*, *jogging* etc

Comment: isn't the hypernym "gaits" ?  or is it different for humans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this page](http://www.vocabulary.com/lists/134884#view=notes) that lists 25 different words for walking, hope it will be useful.

Comment: It's always a good idea to actually list the words in your answer. Links can rot over time and your answer is just a link to a website that may or may not exist next year.

Answer (score 2):

Sauntering, perambulating, strolling, trotting, hopping, dashing, marching, promenading, ambling, trudging, plodding, tramping, trekking, striding, wandering, prowling, roaming, traipsing...

Comment: Perhaps you could list them according to speed/mobility?

Comment: trailing, stumbling, scampering, scurrying, scuttling (I can't think of any others)

Comment: A problem here is: there's a distinct difference between **actual gaits** (eg, run, hop) and just "descriptions of the emotional aspects of travel" (hurried around! promenaded!  cruised! etc)